# External heart rate monitor integration with watchOS 3

Tags: bluetooth, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

I have a watchOS 3 fitness application and some of my users are asking for External Heart Rate Monitor support.  I was hoping that if a heart rate monitor was paired with the watch then I'd get this for "free" using the same mechanism used to get data for the watch heart sensor (HKAnchoredObjectQuery on the HKHealthStore).  That does not appear to be the case.  Any advice on how to support this?  Do I need to integrate by hand using Core Bluetooth?

Comment: It should be the case that when an external heart rate monitor is paired to the watch that your app can observe samples created by it in exactly the same way that heart rate samples from the watch hardware can be observed. Is your app able to read HR samples at all? What troubleshooting have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my problem was using sample code without scrutinizing it.  I removed the following line and now external heart rate monitors work fine:

```
let devicePredicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: [HKDevice.local()])
```

Comment: Could you give us the link to the sample app you have mentioned in your answer.